# Is the Effort Slider relative or absolute?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

In the three stages of development you can move three sliders up and down.  This will affect the time preview of each step along the bottom.

My questions:

- Are the sliders relative, that is if all three sliders where at max is that the same as all three sliders at 50% (or some other equal value)

or

- Are the absolute in that you will spend a longer time in all three, thus creating more dev and tech points, but the stage taking longer to complete?

If the second is true why not be maxed out all the time unless you need cash now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are relative.  Setting them all to the top will give you the same result as setting them all to the bottom.  You need to set them to different levels (relative to each other) in order for them to have an effect.

Comment: +1, couldn't have explained it any better myself.